# Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running? (Whonix)

Tags: linux, whonix

I am relatively new to Tor/Linux/Whonix

My goal in mind is to add bridges to my sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc

I keep getting errors saying basically I can't reach the host servers of these bridges. Then I go to take a look at my tor off a fresh boot. I use sudo netstat -plnt | fgrep 9050

It shows 2 different tcp running and I'm not sure what this means.
I have looked extensively online with many of the same question but not any answers. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Bridges

Answer (score 2):

Good day,

You'll have to run "whonixsetup" after adding your bridges to torrc and reload Tor afterwards.

Either way, going through this should help you get along nicely: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Bridges#How_to_use_bridges_in_Whonix

Have a nice day,

Ego